# FirebaseUI custom layout doesn't show

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have created a custom layout for authentication, but the layout is not shown and Email login screen is displayed instead

```
val customLayout = AuthMethodPickerLayout.Builder(R.layout.custom_signinbasic)
                .setPhoneButtonId(R.id.buttonPhone)
                .setEmailButtonId(R.id.buttonEmail)
                .build()

            startActivityForResult(
                       AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(customLayout)
                .build(),
            Signin_Request_Code)
```

***Layout***

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            android:text="Login with Email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonEmail" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.335"/>
    <Button
            android:text="Login with Phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPhone" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonEmail" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.487" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.067"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***What is displays***

[image]

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: No bro, not happening @Faisal

Comment: I solved this issue. I'll post answer

Comment: ok bro and thanx for it :) @Faisal

Comment: let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Sure will check when free :) @Faisal

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set Provider list:

```
List<IdpConfig> selectedProviders = new ArrayList<>();
            selectedProviders.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build());
            selectedProviders.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build());
```

Kotlin:

```
val selectedProviders = mutableListOf<AuthUI.IdpConfig>()
    providers.add(AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build())
    providers.add(AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build())
```

then create SinginIntentBuilder:

```
            AuthUI.SignInIntentBuilder builder = AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder();
```

Create custom layout as you have already created:

```
            AuthMethodPickerLayout customLayout = new AuthMethodPickerLayout
                    .Builder(R.layout.activity_login) //your layout name
                    .setPhoneButtonId(R.id.buttonPhone)
                    .setEmailButtonId(R.id.buttonEmail)
                    .build();
```

then pass builder and provider and start activity for result:

```
            startActivityForResult(builder.setAuthMethodPickerLayout(customLayout)
                    .setAvailableProviders(selectedProviders)//provider list
                    .setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)//app theme or whatever theme you want
                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                    .build(),RC_SIGN_IN);
```