# FirebaseUI Email starts the Email sign in flow at startup

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm having trouble with the FirebaseUI. The problem is, is that it starts the Email sign in flow at startup without clicking on anything. I want it to show the different sign in options, but it keeps starting the email sign in flow.
I want it to show this:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUlog.png)

But instead it goes directly into the email sign in flow whenever the app starts and without clicking anything. I never get the option to choose Facebook nor Google

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xouDF.png)

This is my LoginActivty

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 7117;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    showSignInOptions();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void showSignInOptions() {
    AuthMethodPickerLayout loginLayout = new AuthMethodPickerLayout
            .Builder(R.layout.activity_login)
            .setEmailButtonId(R.id.email_button)
            .setFacebookButtonId(R.id.facebook_button)
            .setGoogleButtonId(R.id.google_button)
            .build();
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
                    .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(loginLayout)
                    .build(), MY_REQUEST_CODE
    );
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome " + user.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + response.getError().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see anywhere in my code that says it should start the emailflow. Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. All I needed was to use

```
setAvailableProviders();
```

For my SignInIntentBuilder();

Code for my new LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 7117;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome back " + currentUser.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please log in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    showSignInOptions();
}

private void showSignInOptions() {
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = new ArrayList<>();
    providers.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build());
    providers.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build());
    providers.add(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());

    AuthUI.SignInIntentBuilder builder = AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder();
    AuthMethodPickerLayout loginLayout = new AuthMethodPickerLayout
            .Builder(R.layout.activity_login)
            .setEmailButtonId(R.id.email_button)
            .setFacebookButtonId(R.id.facebook_button)
            .setGoogleButtonId(R.id.google_button)
            .build();

    startActivityForResult(
            builder.setAuthMethodPickerLayout(loginLayout)
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                    .build(), MY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome " + user.getDisplayName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + response.getError().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Found a related stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57156257/firebaseui-custom-layout-doesnt-show)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that starts the sign-in flow:

```
startActivityForResult(
    AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
        .setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
        .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(loginLayout)
        .build(), MY_REQUEST_CODE
);
```

`startActivityForResult` does exactly what it says - it starts an activity, and in this case, it's being told to start the Firebase UI activity.  Since you're calling it during onCreate, the current activity will never be visible to the user.

Comment: I know that, but when I run the code it automatically goes into Email sign in. I want it to show the sign in options.

Edit: As u can see, I used setAuthMethordPickerLayout to my custom layout. I followed FirebaseUI's README file regarding custom layout

Comment: I think you might want to edit the question to be more specific about what exactly isn't working the way you expect, and what you want instead.

Comment: I've edited the post. But do you understand what I mean now?

Comment: No, I don't really understand.  Edit the text of the question to explain in more detail.

Comment: I've added pictures that may be helping explaining it for you. Thanks for your advice

Comment: I think my answer still applies - your code is simply launching FirebaseUI as soon as LoginActivity starts, so LoginActivity is never shown.

Comment: But I set the AuthMethodPickerLayout to the activity. I must be misunderstanding how u set custom layout for the firebase ui. Then if it should work, then I should be doing this in the MainActivity?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  The thing you need to do is not call startActivityForResult until you actually want to navigate the user to the Firebase UI.  Right now, you are calling it immediately after LoginActivity starts.

Comment: If I shoulnd't use startActivityForResult, then what method should I use instead? Thanks in advannce

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't use startActivityForResult, I'm saying you shouldn't call it until it's time to transition to the Firebase UI.

Comment: I fixed it. Problem was that I needed to set available providers for my SignInIntentBuilder.